# Lettuce (Redis) + Mybatis (MySQL) take up most of the CPU of Spring Boot app in production - is it normal? how to optimize?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, redis, profiling

today I used https://github.com/async-profiler/async-profiler to check the CPU usage of my Spring Boot app (just a normal backend) in production. Surprisingly, Lettuce (Redis) + Mybatis (MySQL) take up most of the CPU time. I am not talking about wall time here, but CPU time, since I know database requests need to wait for milliseconds and thus wall time will be very long. Therefore, I wonder:

Is it normal or abnormal? (I suspect it is reasonable, given how complex it is to make a database request)

Did you observe that in your code, or it is just me having this issue?

Any suggestions about how to optimize it?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It's common for DB operations to consume a significant amount of CPU. But, it will usually depend on various factors such as complexity of the queries|efficiency of the DB driver|amount of data being processed|available hardware resources

In this situation, it's hard to provide definitive answers without knowing more information about your application, environment and workloads but some general tricks to optimize your springboot app can include (optimizing your queries, caching, tuning DB config, load testing, etc.. optimizations should vary depending on your specific use case, your latency requirements and workloads)